# Winston Logging to File is Delayed, Logging to Console is Not (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, logging, winston

I have a Node.js app that runs shell commands using `execSync` and uses `winston` to log messages to both Console and File transports.

**Problem:** By tailing the log file, we can see that the message being logged to console is not being logged immediately to file until the script has finished running.

Is there a way to get Winston flushing the logs immediately to file?

---

Using node 12.14.1, winston 3.2.1, Ubuntu 18.04.3

**In the middle of the run**

*(Left)* `tail -f logs/test.log`

*(Right)* `node test.js`

[image]

**End of the run**

*(Left)* `tail -f logs/test.log`

*(Right)* `node test.js`

[image]

---

**Nodejs Code**

```
const winston = require('winston');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const options = {
    file: {
        level: 'debug',
        filename: `./logs/test.log`,
    },
    console: {
        level: 'debug'
    }
};

let logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File(options.file),
        new winston.transports.Console(options.console),
    ]
});

logger.info('First log message')

for (const name of ['jack','ryan','tom']) {
    const output = execSync('sleep 1');    // simulate a command that does some work
    logger.debug(name)
}
```

Comment: Is your requirement to log at same time OR make sure you finish both ways before exiting app?

Comment: @AshishModi I need to log both at the approximately time as soon as the `logger.info()`/`logger.debug()` functions are executed, so that we can monitor the logs in almost real-time, by tailing the log files directly and using a centralized logging system such as the ELK stack

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @Naxos84 Not yet

Comment: I have somehow same problem. My problem is when HTTP requests are received by _express_, before passing them into handlers, _winston_ writes into file immediately, but in handlers it doesn't and flush all log entries together after response is returned to client.